# Does the ShapeRange.Export Method no longer work in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I used this method only a few weeks ago and it was working wonderfully, but now I'm getting an error when I try to export shapes as a PNG in my VBA macro. It says that the method is no longer supported by the object.

When I search online, I see the Microsoft has listed the method as "Reserved for internal use" under PPT 2010. When I search the main VBA reference library, it does not list the method at all under the "ShapeRange" object.Does that mean that the method is deprecated? This seems like a very common function that's needed, will it come back?

For reference, here are the two sites I was referring to: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff760411(v%3Doffice.14))

[Powerpoint.ShapeRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange)

And here's the line of code that it's failing on:

```
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Export FilePath & SaveFile & ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG
```

I get the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>   Method 'Export' of object 'ShapeRange' failed

Comment: The error isn't that the object doesn't support that method, but that the method failed. What are your values of `FilePath` and `SaveFile`?

Comment: AFAIK the `Export` method is deprecated but still available to use (worked without errors for me, Office 365).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! FilePath and SaveFile are just 2 strings that I pass in from cells in Excel. FilePath is a string pointing to a Google Drive folder through File Stream. And SaveFile is to name the image. But I think I see my error now - I had a typo in the FilePath. I really should stop working on a few hours of sleep....Thank you for confirming that the method still supported!

Answer (score 0):

Typo in FilePath caused the error. Thank you BigBen for confirming that the method is indeed deprecated but still functioning.

Comment: Glad that you figured out the error! Happy to help out.